# How to close a Java SWT window with a button?

Tags: java, dialog, swt

As a newbie to Java, and many years of iOS and .NET experience, I found this to be massively confusing.  What I want I thought would be very simple - I want a dialog (called from a main window) with OK and Cancel buttons.  When you click OK, it does something, then dismisses the dialog.  When you click Cancel, it just dismisses the dialog.

However, doing this using the SWT shell Dialog class is not obvious.  How do you get a button to dismiss the dialog, and return execution back to the main Window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Shell.close()` rather than `dispose()` - so `shlCheckOut.close()`.

`Shell.close` sends the `SWT.Close` event and then calls `dispose`.

Answer (score 4):

With some trial-and-error and a lot of fruitless searching, I found in your button code, you have to call the .dispose() method of the dialog's shell variable.  For example, my dialog is `CheckOutDialog`, thus I named the shell variable `shlCheckOut`.  In the `createContents()` method, I put the button code as such:

...

```
Button btnCancel = new Button(shlCheckOut, SWT.NONE);
btnCancel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            shlCheckOut.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Shell.close()` is more appropriate

Comment: Greg, thanks - it should be posted as an answer.  So in my example, shlCheckOut.close(); ?

Comment: This looks extremely straight-forward to me. What ways you had tried instead?

Comment: Since I am new to Java, a lot of what may be straightforward to an experienced hand is not to me.  Dispose is not what I would have guessed.  I tried the code assist to browse through the methods, but it wasn't obvious - nor was the Best Practice.

Comment: Hmmm, I get an exception when I call close(), but not when I call dispose().   `Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed`

Comment: ah ha, close() was being called twice.